# shiny object reactivity to several inputs (buttons)

Tags: r, shiny, observers, reactive

I have a shinyapp, in which a main object should be updated depending on the change other objects/inputs (buttons that perform other operations, whose result is not easily tracked, e.g. online data). That's why I had to use the input of buttons. Is there a way to update the main object without having to re-write the code for every button? In my example, I had to use observeEvent two times:

```
library(datasets)
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(    
  titlePanel("Telephones by region"),
  sidebarLayout(      
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                  choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
      helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones."),
      actionButton("submit", 
                   label = "submit"), # this also has other functions
      actionButton("change", 
                   label = "change")  # this also has other functions
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )
  )
)
server<-function(input, output) {
data<-reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$submit,{
  data$data<-WorldPhones[,input$region]
  })
observeEvent(input$change,{
  data$data<-WorldPhones[,input$region]
})
output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
   if(!is.null(data$data))
    barplot(data$data*1000, 
            ylab="Number of Telephones",
            xlab="Year")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply make an expression with both buttons, for example using `c()`:

```
observeEvent(c(input$submit,input$change),{
  data$data<-WorldPhones[,input$region]
  })
```